# Error installing Visual Studio for mac

Tags: macos, macos-sierra, visual-studio-mac

I have a MacBook Air with macOS Sierra 10.12.5. I'm getting the following error trying to install Visual Studio for Mac:

Initial task interrupted by exception
Access to the path "/Users/username/.config/xbuild" is denied.
Exception type: System.UnauthorizedAccessException
Message: Access to the path "/Users/username/.config/xbuild" is denied.
at Xamarin.Web.Installer.TasksManager.DetectComponents () [0x000a1] in /Users/builder/data/lanes/4852/1d420fd9/source/installer/Xamarin.Web.Installer/TasksManager.cs:306

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Are you using an admin account

Comment: Yes @DerekLawrence.

Comment: Do you need xamarin installed? Can you try installing visual studios without xamarin selected. Can always update the instalation after.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Building on @Elvermg's comment with more details:

I ran:

```
$ ls -la ~ | grep .config

drwxr-xr-x    5 root  staff         170 22 Jun 15:08 .config
```

This confirmed the same issue.

I changed the owner of the `~/.config` directory:

```
sudo chown [username]:staff ~/.config/
```

Problem solved.

Comment: thanks a lot. i couldnt install filezilla because of this error too.

Answer (score 1):

Can you try installing this version.

https://dl.xamarin.com/VsMac/VisualStudioForMac-Preview1-7.0.0.347.dmg

Seems the store version might have issues on your version of mac.

Comment: the installation was successful (after installing Mono), but when I ran the application, it sent me to the download page because the preview is not enabled anymore. I'm like in the beginning. :S

Comment: Did it successfully install the android sdk?

Comment: Yes @DerekLawrence, I change the owner of the directory "/Users/username/.config" to my username and then it worked. For some reason the owner and group for "/Users/username/.config" directory was: root:staff.